# Step in proof of Structure Theorem for finitely generated modules over a PID

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, principal-ideal-domains

I'm looking for help with problem #6 on page 189 of Jacobson's "Basic Algebra I".  In particular, we suppose $D$ is a PID and $M$ is a finitely generated module over $D$ with generators $x_1, ... x_n$.  Furthermore, we specify these generators have minimal $n$ and that $l(x_1)$ is minimal among generating sets with $n$ members.  ($l(x)$ is defined to be number of primes in the factorization of $a \in D$ where $\text{ann}(x) = (a)$.  If $a=0$ then we define $l(a) = \infty$.)

Define $N := \sum_{j \ge 2}{Dx_j}$.  The problem claims "To show $\text{ann}(x_1) \supset \text{ann}(y)$ for $y \in N$ it suffices to prove $\text{ann}(x_1) \supset \text{ann}(x_j), j \ge 2$".  Can someone clarify for me why this is sufficient?

Comment: If $d\in D$ kills $y\in N$, then from the decomposition of $M$ into $Dx_j$'s $d$ must kill each component of $y$ in $Dx_j$. So it suffices to show that any $d$ killing $x_j$ kills $x_1$, which is the claim.

Comment: The "d must kill each component of y" isn't obvious.  As stated in question's title, this is part of the proof of the structure theorem, so we can't assume the decomposition that theorem provides

Comment: (I.e., we can't assume the sum is direct, so it isn't immediate that $d$ must kill each component of $y$ in order to kill $y$.)